# Widget in Flutter app does not send string data as expected

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-desktop

I need to make an app which searches a name in an api. The problem is that the form widget doesn't send the name I write on the input.

The part that matters are: `dadosPessoa()`, `Form()` and the both `TextFormField()`

```
        import 'dart:convert';
        import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:async/async.dart';
        import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
        import 'package:convert/convert.dart';

        var nome1 = TextEditingController();
        var sobrenome1 = TextEditingController();
        var nome = nome1.text;
        var sobrenome = sobrenome1.text;
        String responsebody;


        dynamic url = "https://completecriminalchecks.com/api/json/?firstname=$nome&lastname=$sobrenome&apikey=fooberry";

        Future<void> main() async {
          http.Response response = await http.get(url);
          responsebody = response.body;

          Future<String> dadosPessoa() async {
            print(json.decode(responsebody)['person']);
          }

          runApp(MaterialApp(
            home: _Home(),
          ));
        }

        class _Home extends StatefulWidget {
          @override

          __HomeState createState() => __HomeState();
        }

        class __HomeState extends State<_Home> {
          String get resultado => null;

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(
                    "FIVE-0"),
              ),

              body:
              Form(
                child:
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: nome1,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Nome do suspeito:",

                      ),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Digite o nome sugeito';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),


                    TextFormField(
                      controller: sobrenome1,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Nome do suspeito:",

                      ),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Digite o nome sugeito';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print(json.decode(responsebody)['person']);
                        },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: don't post your apiKey online.

Comment: Please take care to ensure that your post looks like you intended. The code snippet here had your image right in the middle, and this would have been very evident from the preview window (as well as what the post looked like after publishing). Thus, the image did not render.

Comment: Also, titles here (and indeed anywhere on the internet) need to be informative. They are like a little advertisement to say what the question is above. "Halp me" and "Need a kind soul" is not useful. Explain what your question is about, so you can attract subject matter experts, and so future readers can see this question if it is helpful for their problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i fixed lots of things in your code and this should looks like this

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: _Home(),
  ));
}

class _Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  __HomeState createState() => __HomeState();
}

class __HomeState extends State<_Home> {
  final nome1 = TextEditingController();
  final sobrenome1 = TextEditingController();
  String responsebody;

  void getData() async {
    String url =
        "https://completecriminalchecks.com/api/json/?firstname=${nome1.text}&lastname=${sobrenome1.text}&apikey=fooberry";
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    responsebody = response.body;

    print(json.decode(responsebody)['person']);
  }

  String get resultado => null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("FIVE-0"),
      ),
      body: Form(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: nome1,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Nome do suspeito:",
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Digite o nome sugeito';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: sobrenome1,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Nome do suspeito:",
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Digite o nome sugeito';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Submit"),
              onPressed: () {
                getData();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

First thing you have assigned `name1` and `sobrenome1` variable to a empty String because `TextEditingController().text` returns the current value of the form which is empty.

```
nome1 = TextEditingController();
 var nome = nome1.text;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Man. I will test right now, but i think you make all my problems with this code desaper. lol.

Comment: Did it worked for you? If then make the answer useful so others will know that's the right answer if not then let me know the error

Comment: hi. sorry. i really forget about this.Marking usefull right now

Comment: man. i dont know how to mark usefull. how i make that?

Comment: Just give a upvote i can't do that because i have answered that question by using up arrow on left side of question.